# VBA + RecordsetClone.FindFirst not working correctly

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have an access application that has been working well for several years that contains around 25,670 records. Until recently, everything was fine. On the form, we have a "go to quote" field to allow the user to position themselves on the quote they wish to work with. The first time i open the form and I enter a record number higher than 25,671, findfirst displays record number "6255". If I enter a record number lower than 25,670 the search is displayed correctly. Second and subsequent use of the "goto quote" field, using the same findfirst processing, takes you to the CORRECT, desired quote number. here is my code:

```
Private Sub Modifiable66_AfterUpdate()
     Me.RecordsetClone.FindFirst "[ProjectNo] = " & Me![Modifiable66]
     Me.Bookmark = Me.RecordsetClone.Bookmark
End Sub
```

I found a solution to make it work but I would like to know if anyone has an idea why after 25670 recording it no longer works as before.

Here is the code that works fine:

```
Private Sub Modifiable66_AfterUpdate()
     Me.RecordsetClone.MoveLast
     Me.RecordsetClone.MoveFirst
     Me.RecordsetClone.FindFirst "[ProjectNo] = " & Me![Modifiable66]
     Me.Bookmark = Me.RecordsetClone.Bookmark
End Sub
```

THANKS :)

Comment: The records in the recordset may not be in the order that you expect. When you ask to find a record that does not exist it just goes to the first record it sees, from a human point of view this is not the "first" record.

Comment: `rs.FindFirst`  ...  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/recordset-findfirst-method-dao

Comment: When you open a form where the recordsource has "many" records, they aren't all loaded immediately. Only if you go to the end, or wait long enough. The same seems to apply to the RecordsetClone. To test this out: open the form, use the record selectors to move to the last record, then run your original sub.

Answer (score 0):

It probably doesn't find the record, thus just returns the last visited.
Try this extended method:

```vb
Private Sub Modifiable66_AfterUpdate()

    Dim Records As DAO.Recordset

    Set Records = Me.RecordsetClone

    If Records.RecordCount > 0 Then
        Records.MoveFirst
        Records.FindFirst "[ProjectNo] = " & Me![Modifiable66]
        If Not Records.NoMatch Then
            Me.Bookmark = Records.Bookmark
        End If
    End If
    Records.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: I just tried this method and it doesn't find the right recording. The only way so far is to put movelast - movefirst

However, this code had been working for at least 10 years without any modification. it seems that the recordings are reaching a limit because if I delete 3 recordings and add 3 it works #1.... strange

Thank you for your time :)

Comment: If the record isn't included in the form's recordset then, of course, it can't be found. So, something else is going on.